# Icons do not display on live

Tags: html, css, icons

I have a web [site](http://serbay.net/demo/serbay4yasinda.com/). The icons are displaying fine on local but they are not displaying on live. For example under the slider there must be a thumb.

```
<span class="icon icon-thumbs-up3"></span>
```

There are `icomoon.eot`, `svg`, `ttf`, `woff` files in `css/fonts` folder. What is the problem?

Comment: please make a fiddle with the specific problematic code. sticking a link to your website and asking whats wrong with icons without explaining a bit about what icons and where is not a good practice.

Comment: please post the relevant code, like the css of the "icon" and "icon-thumbs-up3", and the folder structure on your website that leads to the icon files

Answer (score 0):

Your font face for font icons is:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot@-3m6ikr');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot@#iefix-3m6ikr') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff@-3m6ikr') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf@-3m6ikr') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg@-3m6ikr#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And your font icons css file is in this url `http://serbay.net/demo/serbay4yasinda.com/css/icomoon.css`

So I should be able to download your font icons. In an url address like:

```
http://serbay.net/demo/serbay4yasinda.com/css/fonts/icomoon.eot
```

or

```
http://serbay.net/demo/serbay4yasinda.com/css/fonts/icomoon.woff
```

and etc. But I am not able to download.

so,You should check two cases:

1- Correct font path in: `http://serbay.net/demo/serbay4yasinda.com/css/fonts`

2- Font files permissions.